# How to let jackson generate json string using single quote or no quotes?

Tags: json, jackson, double-quotes

For example, I want to generate a json string for `ng-style`:

```
<th ng-style="{width:247}" data-field="code">Code</th>
```

But with jackson, the result is:

```
<th ng-style="{&quot;width&quot;:247}" data-field="code">Code</th>
```

It's not easy to read.

So I want [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) to generate the json string with single quote or no quotes. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: If you use no quotes or single quotes, that's not JSON.

Comment: But jackson can parse **json** strings which use single quote or no quotes for keys.

Comment: jackson _can_ do several things that are not json

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you have control over the `ObjectMapper` instance, then configure it to handle and generate JSON the way you want:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
```

Comment: Also if you want to be able to read JSONs with single quotes with Jackson:
`mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);`

Answer (score 5):

```
JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES
```

is deprecated, you can use this instead:

```
mapper.configure(JsonWriteFeature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES.mappedFeature(), false);
mapper.configure(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES.mappedFeature(), true);
```

Note that `JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES` is not deprecated (as of now), the corresponding `JsonReadFeature` is mentioned here just for completeness.

Comment: Thanks! The accepted answer is deprecated now

Answer (score -7):

The simplest and the best option is to use regular expression and update the string value.

The sample code is as listed below.

`partNumberList=partNumberList.replaceAll(":", ":\"").replaceAll("}", "\"}");`

The complete code is as shown below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, 
    IOException {
    TestJack obj = new TestJack();
    //var jsonString ='{"it":"Stati Uniti d'America"}';
    //            jsonString =jsonString.replace("'", "\\\\u0027")
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String partNumberList = "[{productId:AS101R}, {productId:09902007}, {productId:09902002}, {productId:09902005}]";
    partNumberList = partNumberList.replaceAll(":", ":\"").replaceAll("}", "\"}");
    System.out.println(partNumberList);
    mapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
    List<ProductDto> jsonToPersonList = null;
    jsonToPersonList = mapper.readValue(partNumberList, new TypeReference<List<ProductDto>>() {
    });
    System.out.println(jsonToPersonList);
}
```

Comment: You should avoid this solution and doing things like it - all the escape sequences will be treated literally - you could possibly end up with an illegal value if there is an escaped double quote or contained single quote - YIKES!